# Passing data in laravel NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I have this view:

```
<div class="window-options">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/api/b/sendInsert/{{$id}}"> 
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 conrol label">Comment</label>
        <input type="text" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Comment">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('b/sendInsert/{$id}, 
Mejili\Core\Controllers\BoardController@insert');
```

My Controller:

```
public function insert($id)
{
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $user = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment = Input::get('inputEmail');
    $comments=new CardComment;
    $comments->commenter_id = $user;
    $comments->card_id = $id;
    $comments->save();
    return Redirect::route('board', $data);
}
```

It throws `NotFoundHttpException`. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show `board` route definition.

Comment: Will you show us your url after submiting form?

Comment: @B.Desai http://localhost:8000/api/b/sendInsert/4

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I want to redirect to the same page

Comment: `{$id}` <--- remove `$` sign

Comment: @Chay22 thanks it worked

Comment: @Chay22 answer so that I can give +

Comment: @Chay22 one last question when I do for `code @foreach ($comments as $cm)
    <p> {{ $cm->id }} {{ $cm->content }}</p>
@endforeach ` Undefined variable: comments

Comment: That's different issue, but afaik, you can't bring any value while redirecting.

Comment: then what should I do in order to run the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dynamic route uri `$id` is being ignored by Laravel as the compiler only accepts `\w` strings. It's defined in `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCompiler` class. So, removing `$` would make it recognized as usual.

```
Route::post('b/sendInsert/{id}', 'Mejili\Core\Controllers\BoardController@insert');
```

Comment: one last question when I do for `code @foreach ($comments as $cm) <p> {{ $cm->id }} {{ $cm->content }}</p> @endforeach Undefined variable: comments

Answer (score 0):

There is mismatch in your form's action path and route

```
action="/api/b/sendInsert/{{$id}}" change route to 
Route::post('api/b/sendInsert/{$id}', 'Mejili\Core\Controllers\BoardController@insert');

Or you can use url() function in action attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain routing, you might want to consider giving aliases to each if your routes.

```
Route::get('sample_route',['as' => "sampleroute",'uses' => "SomeController@somemethood"]);
Route::post('sample_route',['as' => "post_sampleroute",'uses' => "SomeController@submitmethod"]);
```

Given route above are in the same URL by in different HTTP protocols, you can just simply use the route in your form that may look like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('post_sampleroute')}}">
...some inputs here.
</form>
```

A good naming convention to your routes might be a big help for your project. :)

```
$this->group(['as' => "user.", 'prefix' => "user"], function() {
            $this->get('/', ['as' => "index", 'uses' => "UserController@index"]);
            $this->get('create', ['as' => "create", 'uses' => "UserController@create"]);
            $this->post('create', ['as' => "store", 'uses' => "UserController@store"]);
            $this->get('edit/{id?}', ['as' => "edit", 'uses' => "UserController@edit"]);
            $this->post('edit/{id?}', ['as' => "update", 'uses' => "UserController@update"]);
            $this->get('trash', ['as' => "trash", 'uses' => "UserController@trash"]);
            $this->any('restore/{id?}', ['as' => "restore", 'uses' => "UserController@restore"]);
            $this->any('delete/{id?}', ['as' => "destroy", 'uses' => "UserController@destroy"]);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but Chay was the first